# function decorators to specify the first two lines of the def?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm on python 3.5:

I have a repeating pattern in some of my python functions. For a large collection of classes the first two lines are:

```
obj_a = <..... obtain something I need.....>
obj_b = <..... obtain another thing I need....>
```

I'm simplifying it here, but the process of obtaining `obj_a` and `obj_b` isn't a one liner... I would like to avoid repeating this code anywhere in a more elegant way than a util function to obtain `obj_a` and `obj_b` (e.g. `obj_a = getObjectA()`...)

Is there any way to take those lines and put them as part of a decorator of a function where I have something like:

```
@function_where_I_need_my_objects
def foo:
  <....do something with obj_a and obj_b already initialized....>
```

Comment: I take it that these objects need to be generated on command instead of once per execution, otherwise making them optional arguments to the function may be the way to go.

Comment: You are correct about that assumption. thanks.

Comment: so you want to use a decorator to make them exist out of thin air instead of have the first line or two of the function just define them? If there are a lot more then two maybe just have the generating function return a dictionary of them but otherwise I think code that works the way you are suggesting would be fairly confusing to read since `a` and `b` don't have any clear definition but exist anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj_a` and `obj_b` sound a lot like state.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        # These could also be class attributes instead
        # if they can be initialized when Thing is first
        # defined.
        self.obj_a = ...
        self.obj_b = ...

    def foo(self):
        # use self.obj_a and self.obj_b

t = Thing()
t.foo()
```

Defining a decorator that returns a closure around `obj_a` and `obj_b` is also possible.

```
def decorator(f):
    obj_a = ...
    obj_b = ...
    def _():
       # use obj_a and obj_b
    return _

@decorator
def foo():
    ...
```

However, it is hardly any longer and much more flexible to simply write a function that *returns* the two objects, and lets the caller use whatever names they like:

```
def _get_a_b():
    a = ...
    b = ...
    return a, b

def foo():
   obj_a, obj_b = _get_a_b()
   ...

def bar():
    a1, a2 = _get_a_b()
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like the following which creates variables that will effectively become local to the function when it's called. This uses `eval()` which can be unsafe if used on untrusted input, but that is not the case here where it's being used to execute the compiled byte-code of a decorated function (but *caveat emptor*).

```
def local_vars(**kwargs):
    """ Create decorator which will inject specified local variable(s) into
        function before executing it.
    """
    def decorator(fn):
        def decorated():
            return eval(fn.__code__,
                        {k: v() for k, v in kwargs.items()}) # call funcs
        return decorated
    return decorator

def get_object_a(): return 13
def get_object_b(): return 42

# create abbreviation for the long decorator
obj_decorator = local_vars(obj_a=get_object_a, obj_b=get_object_b)

@obj_decorator  # apply decorator
def test():
    print(obj_a)
    print(obj_b)

test()
```

Output:

```
13
42
```

Answer (score -3):

You can put those two objects in a base class as:

```
class TheBaseClass:
    obj1 = something
    obj2 = something_else
```

and inherit this in the functions of classes you need:

```
class Class1(TheBaseClass):
    def func1(self):
       a = self.obj1  # make use of it
       b = self.obj2  # make use of it
```

Comment: Moving them like that changes them from instance attributes to class attributes—which is hardly equivalent—doesn't answer the question.